# Use map() function to read and merge another files list

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

I have three files list

```
filesl <- list.files(pattern = 'RP-L-.*\\.xls', full.names = TRUE)
filesr <- list.files(pattern = 'RP-R-.*\\.xls', full.names = TRUE)
filesv <- list.files(pattern = 'RP-V-.*\\.xls', full.names = TRUE)
```

And I've attemped to read and merge two of them as follows:

```
data <- map2_dfr(filesl, filesr, ~ {
  ldat <- readxl::read_excel(.x)
  rdat <- readxl::read_excel(.y)
  df <- rbind.data.frame(ldat, rdat, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND'))
})
```

If I would like to add the third one list `filesv` what am I supposed to set as function? I guess I should use one from package `purrr` enabling function iteration on multiple elements (such `pmap, imap` and so on, but I am not able to change the commands properly).

Any suggestions as regards

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data <- pmap_dfr(list(filesl, filesr, filesv), ~ {
  ldat <- readxl::read_excel(..1)
  rdat <- readxl::read_excel(..2)
  vdat <- readxl::read_excel(..3)
  df <- rbind.data.frame(ldat, rdat, vdat, by = c('ID', 'GR', 'SES', 'COND'))
})
```

`pmap` takes a list of lists to iterate on. Then the arguments can be referred to as `..1`, `..2`, etc in the anonymous function.

Comment: thank you so much. I though that argurments should have indexed as `.x, .y, .z`

Comment: See e.g. `?map2_dfr` for the relevant documentation, that also includes that of `pmap_dfr` and anonymous function syntax hints

Comment: Btw I'm getting back an error with `rbind.data.frame()`. With those three dataset:  `the nu,ber of arguments columns does not  correspond `

Comment: Could be that `rbind` does not take a `by` argument, but it is hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Then it's likely that the Excel tables have different number of columns. Consider using `dplyr::bind_rows` as a replacement for `rbind`

Comment: It worked. Thanks